# How to update apt repository pakage list in debian offline

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, repository, software-updates

I need to update my system repository package lists (in a simpler phrase :doing `apt update` or `apt-get update`) but I can't connect my machine to the internet .

how can I update package lists offline?

Comment: Is that a "can't" by policy (maybe you're allowed a proxy which could be limited to only let you download from the repos?) or by technology (your system has no network adapter, or it's on a slow/expensive line or something like that)?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz It is a limitation by technology

Answer (score 1):

`apt-offline` is designed for this kind of situation. You’ll have to install it on the offline system, and on a system which has access to the Internet; for the offline system, [download the package manually](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/all/apt-offline/download) along with [any of its dependencies which aren’t already installed](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/apt-offline), and install the packages using `dpkg -i`. The package isn’t actually available in the standard Debian 10 repositories, but it is available in the backports repositories:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports apt-offline
```

Once `apt-offline` is available, you can generate “signature files” on the offline system, which list the files which need to be downloaded on the online system. For `apt update`, run

```
apt-offline set offline.sig --update
```

on the offline system, then transfer the `offline.sig` file to the online system. On the online system, run

```
apt-offline get offline.sig --bundle offline.zip
```

and transfer the resulting `offline.zip` file to the offline system. There, run

```
apt-offline install offline.zip
```

to install the downloaded information.

This will also work for upgrades and package installation; the first step becomes

```
apt-offline set offline.sig --update --upgrade
```

or

```
apt-offline set offline.sig --install package1 package2
```

as appropriate.

Comment: I tried to install `apt-offline` via `sudo apt-get install apt-offline`  but got this error :`E: Unable to locate package`. all of repository sources (main ,contrib and non-free) were enable however I did `sudo apt update` and retried to install but failed again with same error .how can I install it ?

Comment: is `apt-offline` available on the debian apt repositories ?

Comment: Sorry, it’s available in the backports, see my update.

Comment: I downloaded `apt-offline` and its dependencies `.deb` files in a folder and tried to install it on my offline machine with `dpkg -i apt offline ` command but I got dependency error (`dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`)  therefore ,I ran `dpkg --configure -a` but it returned error too and did not work.what is the problem and how can I install `apt-offline` successfully?

Comment: `dpkg` would have listed the missing dependencies; you need to fetch those too.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get install -f` after assuming yes(y) to its prompt , I got hundred lines of error beginning with `E: unable to fetch` and at the last line :`E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?` so, I tried `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` first It listed dependencies and then returned this error message :`E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`.but all of listed dependencies where exist on directory which the main package was srored in  .I've got really confused . what is the problem?

Comment: You need to install the dependencies using `dpkg -i` too, not `apt`.